# Can not Get Variable from GET but can from var_dump($_GET);

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Trying to use a simple AJAX call, where I can pass a variable around and display in the modal. That side works, however I cant retrieve the variable from the GET.

The following `echo var_dump($_GET);` ->

```
array(2) { ["VALUE I WANT"]=> string(0) "" ["_"]=> string(13) "1431441301242" }
```

However, `$TempName = $_GET['Name'];` returns no value?

AJAX:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
   var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
   var modal = $(this);
   var dataString = recipient;


    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "/getEventDetails.php/", 
        data: dataString, 
        cache: false, 
        success: function (data) { 
            console.log(data); 
            console.log(dataString); 
            console.log(recipient); 
            $('.dash').html(data); 
        }, 
        error: function(err) { 
            console.log(err); 
        } 
    });  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't assigned a name to your value in JS. PHP **REQUIRES** form submissions be in `key=value` format so it can built the _GET/_POST arrays. Since you haven't provided a name, there's no key for PHP to build the array with - no key, no value.

Try

```
data: {"foo":dataString}
```

then `$_POST['foo']`.

Alternatively, if you're sending over only a single value, then you can do

```
$value = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

to read the raw post data.

Comment: Perfect - Works using the first method (although I use $_GET). Thanks and I cant accept answer as of yet but I will

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var modal = $(this);
  var dataString = recipient;


$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/getEventDetails.php/", 
    data: {
        recipient: recipient
    }, 
    cache: false, 
    success: function (data) { 
        console.log(data); 
        console.log(dataString); 
        console.log(recipient); 
        $('.dash').html(data); 
    }, 
    error: function(err) { 
        console.log(err); 
    } 
});
```

And in PHP you will get it as

```
$recipient = $_GET['recipient'];
```

[Docs link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).